# Sexp-diff like mode for elisp source diffing

Tags: diff-mode

`diff-mode` shows differences by lines. I'm looking for a mode that could show a diff knowing that the diffed files are elisp sources, so they are full of sexps and therefore more specialized diff highlight could be used.

Is there a mode to show a diff between two sexps or better between two files that are elisp sources?

Example of what I have in mind, instead of the usual:

```
- (unless foo bar baz)
+ (when (foo bar) baz)
```

structural diff:

```
(+when+-unless- +(+foo bar+)+ baz)
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but depending on what you really need, `ediff` (e.g. `ediff-buffers`) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the built-in `ediff` serves great for diffing sexps. As soon as you ignore whitespace, the changes in sexps become very clear.

```
(setq ediff-diff-options "-w --text")
```

A nice command to start with is `ediff-regions-wordwise`, which can be used to narrow the bounds of the stuff you diff.

If you want to diff two sexps very quickly in terms of keys pressed, in `lispy-mode` you can select the first sexp with <kbd>xB</kbd> and compare them with <kbd>B</kbd> from the second sexp.